# Line $CD$ meets the leg $\overline{AB}$ at $P$ and line $BF$ meets the leg $\overline{AC}$ at $Q$. Prove $|AP|=|AQ|$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> $\triangle ABC$ is a right-angled triangle at $A$. There are squares $AEDB$ and $ ACFG$ described from the outside on the legs $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$, respectively. Line $CD$ meets the leg $\overline{AB}$ at $P$ and line $BF$ meets the leg $\overline{AC}$ at $Q$.  Prove $|AP|=|AQ|$.

---

**My attempt:**

If we assume $|AP|=|AQ|$ indeed, then $\measuredangle APQ=\measuredangle PAD=45^\circ\implies\overline{PQ}\parallel\overline{FD}$.

Then $\triangle APQ$ and $\triangle PQF$ have a common edge $\overline{PQ}$ and equal altitudes and, therefore, $\operatorname{Area}(\triangle APQ)=\operatorname{Area}(\triangle PQF)$.

Let $S$ be the intersection point of $BF$ and $CD$.
Then $$\boxed{\operatorname{Area}(\triangle DSQ)=\operatorname{Area}(\triangle PSF)}\tag 1$$

Since $BD\parallel AC$, $\triangle DBQ$ and $\triangle DBC$ with a common edge $\overline{BD}$ have equal altitude and, therefore, $\operatorname{Area}\triangle DBQ=\operatorname{Area}\triangle DBC$
$$\implies\operatorname{Area}(\triangle DSQ)=\operatorname{Area}(\triangle DBQ)-\operatorname{Area}(\triangle DBS)=\operatorname{Area}(\triangle DBC)-\operatorname{Area}(\triangle DBS)=\operatorname{Area}(\triangle BCS)$$
From $(1)$, it follows:
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Area}(\triangle PSF)=\operatorname{Area}(\triangle  BCS)}$$
Picture:

[image]
but I'm not sure if that information is relevant in this proof.

May I ask for advice on how to solve this task?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $AB=c$ and $AC=b$.

Thus, $$\frac{AP}{DE}=\frac{AC}{EC},$$ which gives
$$AP=\frac{bc}{b+c}.$$
By the same way $$AQ=\frac{bc}{b+c}$$ and we are done!

Comment: Thank you very much! I really made it way too complicated.

Comment: @Croissant You are welcome!